# How to format the outputs of several properties of ComponentMeasurements?

Tags: image-processing

I know someone may have asked similar questions but the solution doesn't work to me.

My code is like this:

```
a = ComponentMeasurements[
  MorphologicalComponents[rb], {"Centroid" , "Area"}, #2 > 60 &]
```

My output is

```
{1 -> {{134.861, 140.779}, 65.5}, 2 -> {{168.362, 140.052}, 62.5}}
```

How can I make the output be `{{134.861,140.799},{168.362,140.052}}`?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Have a look at the FAQ for how it is done. I'll do it for you this time...

Comment: @Ajasja Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Part`, or the short hand notation `[[]]`.

```
out = {1 -> {{134.861, 140.779}, 65.5}, 2 -> {{168.362, 140.052}, 62.5}}
out[[All, 2, 1]]
```

produces the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

They are rules:

```
out = {1 -> {{134.861, 140.779}, 65.5}, 2 -> {{168.362, 140.052}, 62.5}}; 
First /@ (Range@2 /. out)
(*
{{134.861, 140.779}, {168.362, 140.052}}
*)
```